# Gravity as a force

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, forces, newtonian-gravity

I want to know if my reasoning is correct.

If you drop an object at a height, the object accelerates downward at a constant rate due to gravity. Because we defined force as the ability to accelerate an object, gravity must also be a force.

And what if the acceleration was $0 \space m/s^2$, would gravity not be a force then, if my reasoning is correct?

Comment: Are you asking if we "dropped" something but it didn't move would we still say a force is acting on it?

Comment: Just because the acceleration equals 0 m/s^2  doesn't mean that the velocity equals 0 m/s. The item drops at a constant velocity toward the Earth, so if my reasoning is correct, gravity wouldn't be considered as a force, right?

Comment: @AustinGae Is your question essentially that objects falling to the ground don't automatically prove the existence of gravity but rather, one needs to verify that the fall has acceleration?

Comment: Sorry, by drop I mean "let go". As in the object does not have an initial velocity. We aren't throwing it.

Comment: Yeah initial velocity = 0

Comment: Feynmans Out for Grumpy Cat, I know that gravity exist, but how do we know that gravity is a force. Do we know that gravity is a type of force because objects accelerate downward? If the objects didn't accelerate downward, would gravity be considered a force is my question.

Comment: Your question is hard to answer because it starts with "if objects didn't accelerate downwards ...". Per standard logic, in a statement of the form "if A then B", if A is false then regardless of what B is, the statement is still true. "If objects didn't accelerate downwards, then gravity is your mother's given name." <-- that statement is true too.

Comment: How would we even be able to say there was anything happening if there was no acceleration? I don't understand. That's like saying if no one is pushing you can you still say someone is pushing you?

Comment: Wait Aaron, you're actually correct. I just realized that after reading your comment. I was imagining the scenario and the object was just stuck in the middle of the air. Ignore the question, but is my reasoning correct?

Comment: Yes. If there is no acceleration then there is no net force.

Comment: In General Relativity, gravity isn’t considered a force.

Comment: @G.Smith Shh... that's a secret

Comment: $a$ can be $0$ half way between two equally massive objects. $f = ma$. If $a$ is $0$, $f$ is $0$. So in that sense, gravity is still a force. If you mean $a$ is always $0$ everywhere, you might say there is no  such force. But that wouldn't happen in our universe.

Comment: As G. Smith says, in G.R. gravity isn't considered a force. An analogy is holding an object on a rocket that is accelerating. If you let go, the object follows uniform linear motion. You accelerate past it. You are free to adopt the point of view that you are motionless. If you do, you are also adopting the point of view that the object is accelerating past you. Gravity works something like that.

Comment: I think you're asking whether detecting an acceleration is necessary to conclude a force, and then I can confidently say "no", your bathroom scale detects a force while you remain stationary. But it's not at all clear to me that this is what you're asking so I voted to close this as unclear.

Answer (score -2):

Your statement

> If you drop an object at a height, the object accelerates downward…

doesn't correspond to reality. If you are in a car and break or accelerate the car, you feel accelerations. If you fall from the sky, you don’t feel any acceleration, you are weightless (as long as the air drag doesn’t impeded the free fall). The same happens, if you are inside the ISS. From the earth I see you moving in a circle every 90 min around the world and comparing this with a weight on a rope, moved in a circle, you has to feel a huge acceleration. But you feel weightless. No force works on you.

> Because we defined force as the ability to accelerate an object, gravity must also be a force.

Gravitation is not a force, it is the ability to bend the geodesic path of any object passing by. The geodesic path for objects with mass small compared to the celestial body depends only from its velocity. Photons have the least curved path with their unsurpassed speed of light. For heavy masses, such as the moon around the earth, the moon makes the earth a little wobbly, but measurable. But anyway, in all these cases the objects are not accelerated.

At the end its a simplification to talk about gravitational *force*. But at the end you are calculating something like instant velocity for some distance from the dropping or the angular velocity for the ISS or the revolution time around the sun.

> > Gravity is most accurately described by the general theory of relativity (proposed by Albert Einstein in 1915) which describes gravity not as a force, but as a consequence of the curvature of spacetime caused by the uneven distribution of mass. (Quote from [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gravity))

Comment: I'm not sure what your paragraph following OP's first quote had to do with OP's quote.  You suggest that an object accelerating downwards when dropped from a height doesn't coorespond to reality... but you don't refute it at all.  Falling through the sky still involves acceleration, even if you don't feel it.  This is also tagged 'Newtonian mechanics' and 'Newtonian gravity'; so it seems fair to say that in this case, referring to gravity as a force is actually appropriate.

Comment: @JMac See my added quote in the answer

Comment: That doesn't really address what I mentioned at all.  Your paragraph about "doesn't correspond to reality" doesn't actually refute or go against what OP said.  You're talking about what is felt, while OP only mentioned acceleration irrespective of feeling.  The ISS still accelerates in Newtonian mechanics, even if the inhabitants can't feel it.  The simplification of gravity acting as a force is _assumed_ when working in Newtonian mechanics, as the question is tagged, so spending so much time addressing the incorrectness of that seems outside of the point.

Comment: @JMac The causality in the question “because something accelerates by gravity it has to be a force” is wrong. BTW, I like to read an answer from you to the question.

Comment: I'm talking about what you have at the start.  "Your statement

If you drop an object at a height, the object accelerates downward…

doesn't correspond to reality. If you are in a car and break or accelerate the car, you feel accelerations. If you fall from the sky, you don’t feel any acceleration, you are weightless"  It's not clear how "If you drop an object at a height, the object accelerates downward" doesn't correspond to reality; nor why the lack of _feeling_ has anything to do with that.  I don't plan on answering because I VTC'd as unclear.

Answer (score -3):

You are asking what would happen if you put (zero relative velocity) an object (with rest mass) into the gravitational field of the Earth.

Now why does it start moving towards Earth? It is because the Universe is set up so and the four vector is set up so, that its magnitude for the massive object must always be c.

> > In physics, in particular in special relativity and general relativity, a four-velocity is a four-vector in four-dimensional spacetime[nb 1] that represents the relativistic counterpart of velocity, which is a three-dimensional vector in space.
> >     in short, the magnitude of the four-velocity for any object is always a fixed constant:
> >     {\displaystyle \|\mathbf {U} \|^{2}=c^{2}\,}  \| \mathbf{U} \|^2 = c^2 \,

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Four-velocity

Now when you put the object into the gravitational field of the Earth, the gravitational field has an effect on the object, as per GR time dilation, the object will feel the passage of time slower relatively.

Since the object start moving in the time dimension slower (because it is in the gravitational zone of the Earth), but its four vector's magnitude needs to stay c, its spatial speed needs to compensate. It will start moving in space.

It will move towards the center of gravity.

As it moves closer to Earth, it moves deeper into the gravitational field. It feels even more gravitational potential (stress-energy).

Can it maintain a constant speed? No. It will feel even more gravitational potential, thus its speed will change, it will increase (accelerate).

Now you are asking can this object maintain a constant speed? The answer is no.

It is very important to understand that this is the reason why the object cannot keep a constant speed as it moves closer to Earth.

Speed is symmetrically relative. Acceleration is absolute.

As per the equivalence principle, the effect of the gravitational zone is the same as acceleration in terms of time dilation.

> > In the theory of general relativity, the equivalence principle is the equivalence of gravitational and inertial mass, and Albert Einstein's observation that the gravitational "force" as experienced locally while standing on a massive body (such as the Earth) is the same as the pseudo-force experienced by an observer in a non-inertial (accelerated) frame of reference.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Equivalence_principle

This is why we call gravity equivalent to the effect of acceleration.

Now you are asking for a gravitational zone, where if you let go of a massive object (zero relative velocity), the object will move toward the center of mass with constant velocity.

There is no such gravitational field in this universe.

Comment: Please read the tags.  The question was directed towards classical/Newtonian physics.  Too much of this answer seems to focus on the GR aspects of gravity.